# Probability with multiple witnesses

Tags: probability

The following situation is in my head since a couple of days, and I can't really think of a good solution to it.

---

A bank robber flies the scene and runs down one of two roads.

On the left road one person (A) claims to have seen the robber. According to some study, that person is 60% reliable. It's not 100%, as other people could have been running as well.

On the right road 2 people (B and C) claim to have seen somebody running. One with confidence 70%, and one with 80%.

```
----A---- Bank ---B----C---
   60%           70%  80%
```

Which road is the most likely that the robber has taken?

---

For the robber to have taken the left road, the people B and C must be wrong, while A can be correct or not (even if the robber took the left road, A could have seen somebody else).

$$p(L) = p(B^c) \cdot p(C^c) = 0.3 \cdot 0.2 = 0.06$$

For the robber to have taken the right road, the person A must be wrong.

$$p(R) = p(A^c) = 0.4$$

The probablility of $p(R)$ is higher, which makes sense (more witnesses and higher probabilities).
However, shouldn't the probabilities add up to 1? We know that the robber took either the left or the right road.

So not all combinations can be possible. E.g. it's not possible that both A and B are correct.
In fact, from the $2^3 = 8$ combinations only $5$ are possible:
$AB^cC^c$, $A^cB^cC^cC, $A^cBC$, $A^cBC^c$, $A^cB^cC$ .
How can I incorporate this fact?

Comment: The rules are not clear.  It seems that $B,C$ might have seen someone else running, no?  You specifically allow for that possibility along the other route.  Given that this is an option, we'd need to have prior probabilities for other runners.

Comment: You've computed the [conditional probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) P(reported sightings | robber went left) and P(reported sightings | robber went right). To convert these into P(left|sightings) and P(right|sightings), which will add to 1, use [Bayes' rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_Theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question we must clarify what does "p reliable" mean. You seems to use the definition that, if one statement is p reliable, then it's true with probability p. However, that does not make sense. As a matter of fact, the statement happens after the event. It's a consequence of the event, rather then the cause of the event. A real observer act in this way: If an event A happens, he will say that "A happens" with probability $1-\alpha$, and "A doesn't happen" with probablity $\alpha$, and $\alpha$ is called "false negative rate"; If A doesn't happen, he will say "A doesn't happen" with probability $1-\beta$, and "A happens" with probability $\beta$, and $\beta$ is called "false positive rate".

To grasp the whole problem we must know another value, the probability of A happens by nature, or the "Priori Probability". Write is as $P(A)$.

So if the observe says "A happens", we can induce that A actually happens with probability
$$P(A|\text{observer claims})=\frac{P(\text{observer claims}|A)P(A)}{P(\text{observer claims})}=\frac{(1-\alpha)P(A)}{(1-\alpha)P(A)+\beta(1-P(A))}.$$

and this is what you called by "reliability".

Now come back to your problem. For a robber that run "randomly" left or right, a reasonable prior probability would be 1/2, so now we solved one unknown number. But only know that A is 60% reliable is not enough to get its $\alpha$ and $\beta$ value. Hence further calculation that utilize all the information to get a more accurate probability is not possible. Nevertheless, we may estimate the result by making assumptions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but that doesn't make much sense since a more well-defined problem is what we need after all.

Finally, this answer is just an intuitive explanation of such kind of problem, and for rigorous and systematic expression you may refer to Bayesian statistics or Mathematical statistics